# Как получить список IAM Role, доступных аккаунту через Amazon EC2 API?

Tags: amazon, api, elasticcloud, sdk

Здравствуйте. Прошу помощи специалистов по Amazon EC2. Есть ли способ получить список IAM ролей, заведенных в консоли EC2 через Java SDK или API Amazon EC2 обычными запросами? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

```
public Collection<String> getIAMRolesRange() {
    AmazonIdentityManagementClient identityManagementClient = new AmazonIdentityManagementClient(new BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccount.getAccessKeyId(), awsAccount.getAccessSecret()));
    ListInstanceProfilesResult listInstanceProfilesResult = identityManagementClient.listInstanceProfiles();
    List<String> iamRoles = new LinkedList<String>();
    for(InstanceProfile instanceProfile: listInstanceProfilesResult.getInstanceProfiles()) {
        iamRoles.addAll(Collections2.transform(instanceProfile.getRoles(), iamRoleToStringFunction));
    }

    return iamRoles;
}
```

Comment: Что в примере значит iamRoleToStringFunction?